# Unity player boxcollider 2d Contacts Normal Vector bug

Tags: unity-game-engine

This bug occurs very rarely (probably 1 in 100 collisions with a platform) where the players box collider 2d have contacts with the platform horizontally (two contacts with (-1,0) vectors and two (intented) with(0,1)). This is very problematic because the player cannot jump forward (just jumps up without any x velocity) and it looks like it hits an invisible wall. I tried increasing the default contact offset in the physics 2D settings to 0.01 but it did not help. I am creating a pixel art game with 16 Pixels per unit. [image]

Comment: I would assume that this only happens when my player hit the edge of a tile and therefore the collision bug happens (like in the picture).

Answer (score 0):

After researching I finally found a fix for my problem. My problem was that the player got stuck inbetween my tiles each having a boxcollider with the TilemapCollider2D. I fixed it by removing each collider to one whole with a composite:

1. add TilemapCollider2D to the tile layer's component
2. check "used by composite" field in TilemapCollider2D
3. set Rigidbody2D to static

- I had to check composite collider to polygons because otherwise I could not apply any Force to the rigidbody somehow.